# Como eu faço Upload de multiplas imagens automaticamente no Firebase Storage - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um app, esse app o usuario ja consegue escolher multiplas imagens, porém eu nao estou conseguindo fazer o upload das imagens escolhidas automaticamente para o Firebase Storage. O usuario ja consegue se autentificar. Alguém pode me ajudar, como fazer esse processo do upload e criar junto pasta que armazenara as imagens atraves de cada id ja autentificado?

```
public class TelaverGaleriaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int SELECAO_GALERIA = 1;
    Button botaoGaleria;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private String identificadorUsuario;
    private List<String> listaFotosRecuperadas = new ArrayList<>();



    //solicitacao de permissao
    private String[] permissoesNecessarias = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_telaver_galeria);

        //configurações iniciais
        storageReference = ConfiguracaoFireBase.getReferenciaStorage();
        identificadorUsuario = UsuarioFirebase.getIdentificadorUsuario();

        //validar as permissoes
        Permissao.validarPermissoes(permissoesNecessarias, this, 1);

        botaoGaleria = findViewById(R.id.botaoParaGaleria);

        //criar evento onclick para que o usuario tenha acesso a galeria clicando no botao
        botaoGaleria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione Imagem"), SELECAO_GALERIA);

            }
        });


    }

    //pegar as  varias foto que o usuario selecionou ok ok ok
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SELECAO_GALERIA) {
            if (resultCode == TelaverGaleriaActivity.RESULT_OK) {

                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                    Log.i("count", String.valueOf(count));
                    int currentItem = 0;
                    while (currentItem < count) {
                        Uri imagemUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(currentItem).getUri();

                        Log.i("uri", imagemUri.toString());
                        listaFotosRecuperadas.add(String.valueOf(imagemUri));
                        currentItem = currentItem + 1;
                    }
                    Log.i("listsize", String.valueOf(listaFotosRecuperadas.size()));
                } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                    String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();



                } else if (listaFotosRecuperadas.size() != 5){
                    exibirMensagemErro("Selecione pelo menos cinco fotos");

                }
                Uri imagemUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("imagens.jpg"));

                StorageReference firebaseRef = storageReference.child( storageReference +imagemUri.getLastPathSegment());
                StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> uploadTask = firebaseRef.putFile(imagemUri);

                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(TelaverGaleriaActivity.this, "Erro ao enviar imagens", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
                        // ...
                        Toast.makeText(TelaverGaleriaActivity.this, "Upload com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }


        }

    }

    private void exibirMensagemErro(String mensagem) {
        Toast.makeText(this, mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

   /* private void salvarImagensFirebase() {
        Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
        StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child(identificadorUsuario+file.getLastPathSegment());
        StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
                // ...
            }
        });

    }*/

    //caso permissao foi negada
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        for(int permissaoResultado : grantResults){
            if(permissaoResultado == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                alertaValidacaoPermissao();

            }

        }

    }
     private void alertaValidacaoPermissao(){
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this );
         builder.setTitle("Permissoes Negadas");
         builder.setMessage("Para utilizar o app é necessario aceitar as permissoes");
         builder.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 finish();

             }
         });
         AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
         dialog.show();
     }



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, Luana!

Talvez esse não seja o melhor método, porém acho que resolverá seu problema.

Primeiro devemos perceber que até o momento, o `SDK` do `Firebase Storage` não suporta upload de múltiplos arquivos de uma única vez. A solução seria chamar várias vezes o código responsável por um único upload. O Segundo ponto que devemos nos atentar é saber quando todos os uploads foram finalizados. Explicado isso, podemos prosseguir.

**1** - Crie uma classe para empacotar algumas informações sobre o upload em si como: `Uri` e uma `flag`  booleana indicando o estado (upado ou não).

**UploadWrapper.java**

```
public class UploadWrapper {
    private Uri uri;
    private boolean uploaded;

    public UploadWrapper(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    /* Getters e setters desnecessários omitidos */

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUploaded(boolean uploaded) {
        this.uploaded = uploaded;
    }

    public boolean isUploaded() {
        return uploaded;
    }
}
```

**2** - Agora amos encapsular o código responsável pelo upload em um método para que possamos trabalhar de forma mais modular, já que iremos utilizar um loop para os múltiplos uploads. Faça que o método receba como parâmetro a classe que criamos no **passo 1**.

```
    public void upload(UploadWrapper wrapper) {
      StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> uploadTask 
= firebaseRef.putFile(wrapper.getUri()); // Isso retorna a Uri da imagem

          uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                   // Setar false aqui é irrelevante, pois o valor padrão já é false,
                   // mas server como ilustração de que o upload dessa imagem falhou
                   wrapper.setUploaded(false); 

                   // Agora adicione o wrapper à lista e cheque se o tamanho dela
                   // é igual ao tamanho da lista de uris: se sim, sabemos que
                   //  não há mais nada para upar e já podemos avisar ao 
                   // usuário
                   if (!mFinished.contains(wrapper)) mFinished.add(wrapper);
                   checkUploadFinished();   // Esse método vai checar se tudo já acabou
              })
              .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                   // Repetindo tudo só que dessa vez setando a flag (uploaded)
                   // como true!
                   wrapper.setUploaded(true); 

                   // Verifica se já não foi adicionado à lista
                   if (!mFinished.contains(wrapper)) mFinished.add(wrapper);
                   checkUploadFinished();   // Esse método vai checar se tudo já acabou       
              }
           });
    }
```

**3** - Precisamos criar agora um método que verifica quais imagens foram upadas ou não.

```
public void checkUploadFinished() {
   if (listaFotosRecuperadas.size() == mFinished.size()) {
        // Pronto! Todos os uploads foram concluídos e você
        // pode verificar quem teve sucesso ou falha na lista mFinished
        for(UploadWrapper wrapper : mFinished) {         
           if (wrapper.isUploaded) {               // Mas isso é opcional, você pode só mostrar um Toast
               // Foi upado com sucesso!
           }
        }

       // E não esqueça de esvaziar as listas depois que tudo acabar
       listaFotosRecuperadas.clear();
       mFinished.clear();  
    }
}
```

**4** - Por fim, crie um loop para montar os `wrappers` e chamar o método de upload várias vezes.

```
for (String s : listaFotosRecuperadas) {
    upload(new Wrapper(Uri.parse(s)));
}
```

Ah, ia me esquencendo, sobre o local das imagens: faça da seguinte forma

```
StorageReference firebaseRef = storageReference.child("galleries/" + mUserKey);
```

Assim o `Firebase Storage` gerá um esquemas de diretórios desse modo

```
   galleries/{id_do_usuario}/imagem_1.jpg
    .
    .
    .
    galleries/{id_do_usuario}/imagem_n.jpg   // n imagens
```

E caso o diretório não exista, ele será criado automaticamente. Não se preocupe quanto a isso.

Aviso que não testei esse código então não sei se na prática tudo ocorrerá como esperado. De qualquer modo, esse é o caminho. Espero que isso ajude!

Comment: Boa noite Ivan tudo bem? eu testei o código que você me passou adaptando ao projeto, mas nao obtive sucesso. Então eu analisei o conteudo novamente e eu nao precisei mudar muita coisa. Em Activity result refiz o contador chamando a lista de imagens escolhidas, criei um metodo apenas para pegar os arquivos e estanciei, e dentro ainda do  Activity result usei StorageReference com child para chamar o idusuario (que eu ja tinha criado uma classe), e criar uma pasta para cada id. Agora cada usuario ao escolher as fotos possui cada um pasta específica, Ivan mesmo assim eu agradeço, gratidão.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado de alguma forma. Abs!